# CRM Dynamics Online 2016 Azure SDK for Java receive BrokeredMessages with 500 error code

Tags: java, azure, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a problem with CRM Dynamics Online 2016 Azure SDK for Java.
I can connect to Azure Service Bus, I can see queues and message count in queues, but cannot receive messages. Message Id is null and message body contain 500 error

> `500`The server was unable to process the
>   request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please
>   contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id.
>   TrackingId:acf8a543-33c9-486d-b13b-443823e6c394_G9,TimeStamp:4/13/2016
>   7:26:22 AM. If the problem persists, please contact
>   your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id.
>   TrackingId:acf8a543-33

Is there any working sample on the Internet to solve the problem?

Test code:

```
@Test
public void readAllExistedMessagesFromAllQueue() {
    try {
        ServiceBusContract serviceBusContract = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithConnectionString(null, Configuration.load(), ASB_CONNECTION_STRING).create(ServiceBusContract.class);

        ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
        opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);

        ListQueuesResult result = serviceBusContract.listQueues();
        if (result != null && result.getItems().size() > 0) {
            for (QueueInfo queueInfo : result.getItems()) {
                logger.debug("queu: " + queueInfo.getPath() + " MessageCount: " + queueInfo.getMessageCount());

                for (int i = 0; i < result.getItems().size(); i++) {
                    BrokeredMessage message = serviceBusContract.receiveQueueMessage(queueInfo.getPath(),
                            opts).getValue();
                    if (message == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.print("__________________________________________");
                    System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getMessageId());
                    System.out.print("From queue: ");
                    byte[] b = new byte[200];
                    String s = null;
                    int numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                    while (-1 != numRead) {
                        s = new String(b);
                        s = s.trim();
                        System.out.print(s);
                        numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: please give out your code

Comment: added the code to question

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, according to the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/services/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/servicebus) and [javadocs](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/servicebus/package-frame.html) of Service Bus, the `ServiceBusContract` is a Java interface, that you can't directly create an instance of the interface `ServiceBusContract`.

So please try to use the code below from [the section `Create a queue`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/#create-a-queue) of the document "How to use Service Bus queues".

```
Configuration config =
        ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(
                "<your-servicebus-namespace>",
                "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                "<SAS-key-value>",
                ".servicebus.windows.net"
                );

ServiceBusContract serviceBusContract = ServiceBusService.create(config);
```

---

**Update**

You can find the `SharedAccessKeyName` & `SharedAccessKey` in the connection string via click the button below at the bottom of your service bus page.

[image]

Then, show the view below and copy the `CONNECTION STRING`.
[image]

The connection string like this below.

> `Endpoint=sb://<your-servicebus-namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<SAS-key-value>`

Please copy the correct part of connection string instead of the related part of the code.

Comment: This kind of connection gives following response 'Response Body: <Error><Code>401</Code><Detail>Manage claim is required for this operation. TrackingId:92a0330b-a3cb-429f-b57a-4f4afa1490a8_G44,TimeStamp:4/14/2016 7:34:12 AM</Detail></Error>'

Comment: @KarlisAcc The 401 error code means "Authorization failure". Do you use the correct sas key for the `Configuration`? Please see my updated content.

Comment: My ASB_CONNECTION_STRING is "Endpoint=sb://<name_space>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=<Issuer>;SharedSecretValue=<Value>";

Comment: @KarlisAcc Where is the connection string you copied from?

Comment: I received it as connection string, what to use to connect ASB

Comment: @KarlisAcc Please refer to my post updated content and copy the connection string on Azure old portal, and try to run your app again.